# Meteor JS - Twitter API 400 error

Tags: twitter, meteor

I have been trying to access twitter's api via Meteor but have been having problems properly authenticating my request.

I have tried working with the streaming API as well as the Rest API. I'm currently focused on the rest API.

Here is the code for my GET request

```
Meteor.methods({
checkTwitter: function() {
var result = Meteor.http.call("GET", 
'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json',
{
content: 'application/json', //application/json
timeout: 30000,
headers: {
Authorization : 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="g5uVCKU3QUHBydsMgceIhQ",oauth_nonce="6c34c5c8de9169f1b9dfc08659a3f706",oauth_signature="DA0HwxO6yW6Ow2XTNZb79Xkxwoc%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1367030141",oauth_token="5754612SfpuVX8xxLAjD6md5bmJUXQWNnWj8tXMftlnNHcJxT", oauth_version="1.0"'
}
}
);
console.log(result);
return result;
}
})
```

Here is the logged response:

```
{ statusCode: 400,
content: undefined,
headers: { 'content-length': '0', connection: 'close' },
data: null,
error: [Error: failed]
}
```

I've looked through the meteor docs but their simple examples are not covering my case. thanks for the help.

Comment: never mind.. was able to get the rest API get user timeline working.